# Getting Undefined subroutine utf8::SWASHNEW called at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 109

Tags: bugzilla, strawberry-perl

I am trying to install Bugzilla. For that `Strawberry perl`, `Microsoft IIS`, `MySQL` are installed with latest versions. Followed guidelines given on Bugzilla installation page for windows.

Whenever I run `checksetup.pl`, all necessary `perl` modules related to Bugzilla are installed correctly. Only three optional modules were not installed (`perl-ldap`, `mod_perl` and `Apache-SizeLimit`). And then it is showing an error:

```
Undefined subroutine utf8::SWASHNEW called at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 109.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move back to Strawberry Perl 5.28.2.1 from 5.30.0.1
I had same problem. This fixed.

Comment: Thanks. @YZCarver this will work perfectly. New update of Strawberry PERL was come in last month only.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by applying ***the first*** of the following patch
(use

`locate Safe.pm`

to find the offending file)

DISCLAIMER - AT YOUR OWN RISK

[Perl on github, patch for bug 17291](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/17291/commits/13969e4387da40d425a779b7c8d9c1c0d1d0400e)